# Auto create and pass multiple inputs to a function

Tags: python

I used a for loop to construct a dictionary:

```
dict = {}

for i in np.arange(0, n):
    dict[i] = some_data[i]
```

Then I want to pass the items of the dictionary to a function:

```
function(dict[0], dict[1], dict[2], ... dict[n])
```

As `n` tends to vary between different datasets, is there a way for me to pass multiple inputs to the function without having to manually input `dict[0]` to `dict[n]` every time?

I tried to construct an array of `[dict[0], dict[1], ..., dict[n]]` but the function did not accept an array as the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Yes! This and Grismar's reply answered my question perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, it's called spreading:

```
some_data = [4, 5, 6]

# here's another trick:
d = dict(enumerate(some_data))
print(d)


# some function that takes multiple arguments
def f(*args):
    print(*args)


# calling such a function with the values of your dictionary, as requested
f(*d.values())
```

Result:

```
{0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6}
4 5 6
```